# When are two resolutions of a coherent sheaf homotopic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on a projective manifold $X$. It is well known that one can construct a resolution of $\mathcal{F}$ by holomorphic vector bundles (locally free sheaves).

Are two such resolutions homotopic? Any reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Crossposted at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305951/when-two-resolutions-of-coherent-sheaves-are-homotopic) at the same time it was posted here. Please see [meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5012/can-i-ask-a-question-on-mathoverflow-and-also-on-another-site) for site rules about cross-posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this were true, then any short exact sequence of vector bundles would split. Indeed, if $0 \to \mathscr E_1 \to \mathscr E_2 \to \mathscr E_3 \to 0$ is a short exact sequence of vector bundles, then both
\begin{align*}
K^\bullet = \cdots \to 0 \to \mathscr E_1 \to \mathscr E_2 \to 0 \to \cdots
\end{align*}
and $L^\bullet = \mathscr E_3[0]$ are resolutions of $\mathscr E_3$. If $g \colon L^\bullet \to K^\bullet$ is a homotopy equivalence (or even a quasi-isomorphism!), then the map $g^0 \colon \mathscr E_3 \to \mathscr E_2$ induces an isomorphism
$$\phi \colon \mathscr E_3 \stackrel\sim\to H^0(K^\bullet) = \mathscr E_3.$$
Then $g^0 \circ \phi^{-1} \colon \mathscr E_3 \to \mathscr E_2$ is a splitting of $0 \to \mathscr E_1 \to \mathscr E_2 \to \mathscr E_3 \to 0$. $\square$

(On the other hand, there does always exist a quasi-isomorphism $K^\bullet \to L^\bullet$ in this case, just not in the other direction.)

An example of a short exact sequence of vector bundles that doesn't split is the Koszul sequence
$$0 \to \mathcal O_{\mathbf P^1}(-2) \stackrel{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-y \\ x\end{smallmatrix}\right)}\longrightarrow \mathcal O_{\mathbf P^1}(-1) \oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbf P^1}(-1) \stackrel{\left(x\ \ y\right)}\longrightarrow \mathcal O_{\mathbf P^1} \to 0$$
on $X = \mathbf P^1$. Indeed, $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal O_{\mathbf P^1}, \mathcal O_{\mathbf P^1}(-1) \oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbf P^1}(-1)) = 0$.

Answer (score 7):

No. The simplest example is given by the following two resolutions of the structure sheaf of a point $P \in \mathbb{P}^1$:
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1) 
\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}
\to \mathcal{O}_{P} \to 0
$$
and
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2) 
\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)
\to \mathcal{O}_{P} \to 0
$$
(the second is obtained from the first by a twist).